# pandas_profiling main method not working correctly on Windows 10... Constructor works but not method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-profiling

df.profile_report() fails immediately after installation using
import pandas_profiling

The package is installed properly, because I can generate a report in Jupyter by importing and using just the constructor ProfileReport(df).  However, the syntax df.profile_report() does not work.

When I run df.profile_report() I get an error message below:

````
```AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
----> 1 df.profile_report()

C:\Anaconda3\envs\quantecon\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in getattr(self, name)
5065 if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5066 return self[name]
-> 5067 return object.getattribute(self, name)
5068
5069 def setattr(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'
```
````

Version information:

- Python 3.7.1
- pandas==0.24.2
- Windows 10 2022H2

  ````
  import pandas as pd
  from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

  # The dataframe is the same as the tutorial example given by the author.  

  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])    

  df.profile_report() # this fails.```
  ````

What else I've tried that does work is as follows:
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
...steps to create dataframe df
ProfileReport(df)

Using the constructor ProfileReport(df) by itself at least gets me a report in my Jupyter Notebook. Because of this I know the package is installed and working. However, the object.method() route to get the report doesn't work. But many other methods rely on the object.method() syntax.

## I cannot get any dataframes work with the df.profile_report() method.

````
```import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

# The dataframe is the same as the tutorial example given by the author.  

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(100, 5),
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
)    

df.profile_report() # this fails.
ProfileReport(df)  # this works, but `df.profile_report()` does not work.
```
````

My guess as to what's wrong...?

Since the pandas error is referring to "generic.py" for Pandas Core DataFrame, and the error is "no attribute 'profile_report', perhaps it is the decorator that wraps the dataframe object and modifies it to give it the extra attribute method of .profile_report() ?? That is my guess. I don't know what's causing the error, since it works when I "peek under the covers" and use the report constructor directly. I just cannot use the other methods that rely on the object.method() syntax.

Comment: did you try using `import pandas_profiling` instead of `from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions first.  When I run :  `import pandas_profiling df.profile_report()`   ...   I get the message :  `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) in <module> -> 1 df.profile_report()
C:\ ... site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
-> 5067  return object.__getattribute__(self, name) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'      ( I had to delete some characters to be under the 500 character comment limit. )

Comment: I am sorry but you did not read my question correctly.  I tried exactly what is suggested in the github repository for installation and usage, and what you suggest, but it does not work.  I will try it in a different virtual environment to see if I can isolate the problem to my Python package set.  I am getting a Pandas error, not pandas_profiling error.   "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report' "       See above for the original error.

Answer (score 0):

The `.profile_report()` syntax was introduced in `pandas_profiling` version 2.

You can install this version via pip: `pip install pandas-profiling`.

**EDIT**

The way to import the package is:

`import pandas_profiling`

in contrast to your current approach

`from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`

Comment: I've edited the answer, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for google colab

```
!pip uninstall -y pandas-profiling

!pip install -U pandas-profiling
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and yet I need to run it locally, not on a cloud platform.  What pandas_profiling and pandas versions are you running?

Answer (score 0):

The method that works is:

Follow:

`pip install ydata-profiling`

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Then write your code

```
report = ProfileReport(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import pandas_profiling

pandas_profiling.describe_df(data_df)
html_str_output = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data_df)
```

Comment: This alternative worked for me (where the df.profile_report() did not ... but used to).   

In a notebook, you can display the report inline with this:   
`pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)`

Or output to an HTML file:   
`html_str_output = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)`
`html_str_output.to_file('test_output.htm)`