# Unable to save ProfileReport generated using pandas ydata_profiling library due to an error raised in describe.py

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

**Problem:**
I am using the ydata_profiling library to generate a profile report on my data set and store it as a html file. I appear to be able to generate the report but when I attempt to save it as a html file I receive the following error:

*File "/Users/jt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py", line 253, in description_set\n    self._description_set = describe_df(\n', '  File "/Users/jt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/describe.py", line 57, in describe\n    raise ValueError("Can not describe a `lazy` ProfileReport without a DataFrame.")\n']*

**Relevant Code:**

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport #https://pypi.org/project/ydata-profiling/
#1. get data and mask (indicating which features to analyse)
self._data_df = pd.read_csv(self.inputfname_csv, header=0)
self._mask_df = pd.read_csv(self.inputmask_csv, header=0)
#2. drop unwanted cols
self._selected_columns = self._mask_df.columns[self._mask_df.isin([MASK_ON]).any()]
self._selected_columns = self._selected_columns.values.tolist()
self._data_df = self._data_df.drop(columns=[col for col in self._data_df if col not in self._selected_columns], inplace=True)
#3. generate report
self._data_report_df = ProfileReport(self._data_df, title="Pandas Profiling Report")
#4. save report in html format
self._data_report_df.to_file(self.outputfname_html) # exception raised here!!!
```

**Environment:**

```
Apple MacBook Pro M1 chip
macOS==Ventura 13.4.1 (c)
Visual Studio Code Version 1.72.2
python==3.10.12
conda                         23.7.2
joblib                        1.3.0
matplotlib                    3.7.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
modin                         0.23.0
numba                         0.57.0
numpy                         1.23.5
pandas                        2.0.3
pandas-profiling              3.6.6
scikit-learn                  1.3.0
scipy                         1.11.1
seaborn                       0.12.2
ydata-profiling               4.5.0
zstandard                     0.19.0
```

**Thanks for your time and any help much appreciated**

I have attempted possible solutions detailed in the following websites:

- [pandas_profiling main method not working correctly on Windows 10... Constructor works but not method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816161/pandas-profiling-main-method-not-working-correctly-on-windows-10-constructor/56893869#56893869)
- [getting an error while working on Pandas-profiling on Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652254/getting-an-error-while-working-on-pandas-profiling-on-jupyter)
- https://saturncloud.io/blog/solving-the-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-profilereport-in-pandasprofiling/

Comment: Does behavior change when you delete `, inplace=True` ? (Typically you want to avoid that kwarg -- better to just a create a new DF which shares references to some elements with the old one.) Also, I assume the report works fine with the raw (unmasked) DF you loaded from `inputfname_csv` ?

Comment: Yes on both counts. Removing `inplace=True` generated the report AND enabled me to store it to an html file!! Yay! Many thanks J_H for your solution! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that `, inplace=True` keyword, as it is not doing you
any favors, and it leaves you with a more tangled nest of references
in the result object.

Typically you want to avoid that kwarg -- better to just a create a new DF which shares references to some elements with the old one.

I have only encountered the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning` a few times,
but that was a few too many and I changed my habits. Please refer to
[Inplace Considered Harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208).